# How to write to a text file in python in a ROS node?

Tags: ros, python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to record a  topic message called "message" only when a "message sent" button is pressed. I have made a separate node for GUI that has "message sent" button. I also wrote the "message" topic to a text file when "message sent" button was activated. The program works fine when this node is run separately, it also writes the message to the designated text file. But when I run this node along with other nodes by including it in a launch file, the text file does not seem to be created. Is there any specific reason for this to happen? How can this problem be solved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235830/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-in-python-in-a-ros-node?/) by [Ros User](https://answers.ros.org/users/26709/ros-user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using `roslaunch` the nodes are run from `$ROS_HOME` which is almost always `~/.ros`. So, if you are writing `x.txt` you should be able to find it at `~/.ros/x.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0